# AdWords API Unregistered scope

Tags: oauth, google-ads-api

Good afternoon!
I'm trying to start working with adwords api, I created the adwords identifier and OAuth2 keys by the instruction, I try to get a token through GetRefreshToken by clicking on the link
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=***.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www. googleapis.com/auth/adwords`

I get a 403 error:

`Error: restricted_client Unregistered scope (s) in the request: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adword`

Tell me what's wrong with what I'm doing?

[image]

Comment: Have you registered the client for the scope? https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying it with the same email linked with AdWords? Please try logging into your account and then try the same call. There might be some cache issue of your browser

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same email address id which is linked with Adwords